# Camera screen orientation issue in titanium appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have some issue in device orientation. What i did is that, i have to open camera for screen capture. The camera view is customized by using overlay. Overlay contains a button view, when click on it it will capture image.

I implement device orientation in it. When custom camera opens it looks fine. But when we rotate(that is, rotate to 180 degree) the over lay looks fine, but the camera view inverted the screen. That is for example, if we wish to capture a tree  by rotating device, it'll see like upside down and when after capture, the image also inverted. Does anybody have any idea about how to remove this camera invert while rotating.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is headache for many devs.

How do you rotate the camera? You have to rotate your overlay and pretend user that user is rotating the camera.

To get More info [see this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148581/issue-with-images-auto-rotating)

Explanation is good.

Comment: Hi, My project is in appcelerator studio. I just simply did android:screenOrientation="unspecified" in tiapp.xml. or by default the customised camera view overlay rotates by giving autorotate in overlay. only issue is overlay rotation is fine while rotating but when we rotate to 180 degree by opening camera view, the camera view shows as inverted screen.... no idea how to relovw it :(

Comment: Did you check this link https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148581/issue-with-images-auto-rotating

Comment: ok give me some time, i will post my actual code...may be later today